# Why my carObject move to z-axis?

Tags: unity-game-engine, forward

[image]

Hi, I just made a script to move a car around Unity.
But I see my car moving not only on the x-axis, but also slightly on the z-axis. Is this normal?
And I don't know how to upload pictures, but did I post them correctly?

**CarMove.cs**

```c#
public class CarMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 10.0f;

    void Update () {
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Car is a child of Map.So it will move relative to parent.You could check your Map position or use transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unity Vector3.froward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd0CI.png)

Because simply, Unity Vector3.forward is an abbreviation of Vector3(0, 0, 1) which adds 1 unit to the z axis.

You can check here as well :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Happy coding!